# Pass results of Oracle function as a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I am looking to run a query that can bring back results when I run this:

```
select * from table where table_id in (select function_name(123) from dual);
```

function_name(123) is a function that I pass a value to that outputs values back that are a table (usually several hundred records as a result).

When I run select statement, I get the following error:

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got TYPE_ID_TABLE

I am not sure why? The results coming back from the function contains all values which are NUMBERs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to call a table valued function in Oracle is something like this:

```
select *
from table
where table_id in (select * from table(function_name(123));
```